# How to mass update in scala-activerecord

Tags: scala, activerecord, orm, sql-update, squeryl

I want to update multiple record in a database with a single SQL query. There is a method `forceUpdate`, which can be used like this:

```
case class Document(size: Int, var status: String) extends ActiveRecord
object Document extends ActiveRecordCompanion[Document]

Document.forceUpdate(_.size < 100)(_.status := "small")
```

However, it bypasses the validations and hooks like `beforeSave()`. I tried underlying squeryl:

```
Document.inTransaction {
  update(Document.table)(d =>
    where(d.size < 100)
    set(d.status := "small")
  )
}
```

But it also ignores hooks.

I can't seem to find a method that updates multiple documents at once, while using hooks and validations. Is there at least some workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do a partial update, you are updating some unknown number of records that match your criteria *without* retrieving them.  For the hooks to get triggered though, the object getting updated needs to be known (i.e. retrieved).  The best alternative I can think of would be to retrieve all of the the objects you are updating and then use a [batch update](http://squeryl.org/inserts-updates-delete.html) rather than a partial update.  This won't be as fast or efficient as the partial update you are doing, but unless you can register your hook in the database I don't know what the alternative would be.